# PHPの6文字以上の半角英数字の正規表現について

Tags: php

PHPの6文字以上の半角英数字の正規表現作成中に
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/',($_POST['password'])) !== 6
と
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/',($_POST['password'])) >= 6

この2パターンで試したのですが、上手く動作しませんでした。
お手数をおかけしますがご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match` の返り値は、マッチした (=1) かマッチしないか (=0) であり、文字数ではありません。

正規表現で文字数を指定したい場合、`{N}` や `{n,m}` のような書式を使います。
元のコードに当てはめるなら

```
if( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}$/',($_POST['password']) ) {
    // a-zA-Z0-9 の6文字ちょうどにマッチ
}
```

もしくは、単純に文字数を確認するなら `strlen`, `mb_strlen` 等を使う方法もあります。

Answer (score 0):

これでどうでしょうか。

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{6,}$/i', $_POST['password'])) {
    echo "英数字6文字以上です。";
}
```

{6,} = 6文字以上。
スラッシュ直後の「i」 = 大文字小文字を区別しない。